# Path a photon or phonon takes in a moving medium

Tags: waves, photons, refraction, phonons

Lets say we have a medium with refractive index n whose velocity is given as a function of height.

$v_x(y)=ay$

How would we go about finding the motion of a photon or phonon in this space from the perspective of an observer? I'd imagine the wave particle's path would turn at some point, otherwise it'd be straight and keep going until it's stationary to the observer and moving in the exact opposite direction of the medium it's in.

Comment: Photons are not traveling particles that take paths. Same for phonons that are also non localized collective excitations. Interestingly photons - IMHO - can be better understood by understand the analogy with phonons.

Comment: You know how a ray of light travels on a set path? That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: Use the rest frame of the medium.